# How to login from code

Tags: c#, web, autologin

I need to download page sources from site "hh.ua", but first I have to login. I tried many different methods, but logging failed. Action source of that page is "http://hh.ua/logon.do", I tried to monitor the query sent for logging, it is - http://hh.ua/logon.do?username=111&password=333&action=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8. Please, help!)

Here is code

```
        string formUrl = "http://hh.ua/logon.do"; 
        string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&action=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8", "anli_@mail.ru", "80903798516");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
        return cookieHeader;

        string pageSource;
        string getUrl = "http://hh.ua/resume/ae23733eff00c000df0039ed1f476831706856";
        WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I know about failing of logging because downloaded page is login page.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in code?  What are you automating?

Comment: You need to add more details to your question, such as how do you know logging in failed? What message do you get back, or what happens when you attempt to login as you describe?  Also, post some code.  We cannot guess what is happening.

Comment: I need to find and cut some information from pages of that site.

Comment: Trying to login with GET? Wow, that's secure.

Comment: @Gabe I hardly think the login method in under OP's control.  He is trying to log into the site via code, if that's how the web site does it, it's a non-issue to this question.

Comment: @gmagana, I don't care what you think. It's not secure.

Comment: @Gabe, you're fighting your war in the wrong place. It does not matter if it's secure or not. [/PissingMatch]

Comment: @gmagama, not exactly. I am pointing out that it's not secure. If I had an answer, I would have put it in the appropriate section, not in the comment section. I don't need your permission or instructions on how to use SO.

Answer (score 0):

For those projects that involve a lot of web back and forth, I find [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) very useful. While WatiN may have origins in the test-driven world, it's pretty good at anything that needs to steer a web browser (now with Chrome and Firefox support :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this technique that I describe here to auto login:
http://codecube.net/2010/02/reusing-phpbbs-authentication-system/